# How to call MinimumSpace or Space value in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In Inno Setup we have `WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Caption` which calls `Space` (MinimumSpace) via `[mb] StringChange function`. How to call `Space` or `[mb]` for custom `TLabel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [`ExpandSetupMessage`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Wizard.pas#L295) function that internally calls [`ExpandSetupMessageEx`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Wizard.pas#L284), which expands message arguments like `[kb]` or `[mb]`. Unfortunately, it is not published for Inno Setup Pascal Script.

So, your manual evaluating of these arguments is the only possible way to have at this time.